# Azure Webapp Startup Command is reset after deploy (Visual Studio -> Publish)

Tags: visual-studio, azure

I have a Azure Linux Web App with a custom Startup Command "sh /home/custom_startup.sh". Whenever I re-deploy the app via Visual Studio the Start Command is changed to something like "dotnet App.dll". I don't want this behaviour since at the moment I need to after every deploy change the Startup Command manually and restart the application.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you want to execute a specific script every time you publish, right? The start command is responsible for starting the main project, which is executed after the release is complete.

Comment: So I recommend you to use `PostDeploymentActions`, you can check related information, if this is what you want, do you mind if I send out my answer?

Comment: After the deployment is complete I want the startup command to be pointing to "sh /home/custom_startup.sh" in the configuration in Azure so that it's run first as soon as the app starts. I don't want to run a script via Visual Studio and still have the Startup Command set to "dotnet App.dll" on Azure.

Answer (score 0):

The custom startup command must be added to the Publish profile file. Add this to "Properties\PublishProfiles\Your.pubxml":

```
<AppServiceStartupCommand>sh /home/custom_startup.sh</AppServiceStartupCommand>
```

Publish behavior changed over the years.

- Until 2020 re-deploying an Azure Linux web app did not overwrite its Startup Command. We could just write e.g. "sh /home/custom_startup.sh" in the Azure Portal and forget about it.
- In 2021 re-deploying an Azure Linux web app started overwriting its Startup Command with "dotnet YourEntryPoint.dll". This solved some problems because the runtime couldn't always detect the entry assembly. This however caused the problem of the OP - we were unable to automate a custom Startup Command.
- The solution was a new .pubxml property called AppServiceStartupCommand but [it was released in 2022](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/azure-linux-web-app-startup-command-being-overrite/1456105).

Answer (score 0):

In my case i needed to change the startup command in my Azure App Service using my publish profile to follow the DataDog instructions to configure the monitoring my servelles app.

Then i used the following tag in my web deploy publish profile and worked every fine:

```
<AppServiceStartupCommand>curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DataDog/datadog-aas-linux/v1.5.0/datadog_wrapper | bash</AppServiceStartupCommand>
```

[Data Dog - Azure App Service - Linux Code](https://docs.datadoghq.com/serverless/azure_app_services/azure_app_services_linux/?tab=nodenetphppython#setup)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).